# Why doesn't $\int_C \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$ always vanish?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator, stokes-theorem

**Stokes Theorem** tells us that when $S$ is a piecewise-smooth surface that is bounded by a simple, closed, piecewise-smooth boundary curve $C$ with positive orientation and $\mathbf{F}$ is a vector field whose components have continuous partial derivatives on an open region in $\mathbb{R}^3$ containing $S$, then we have $$\int_C\mathbf{F }\cdot d\mathbf{r}=\iint_S \mathrm{curl }\ \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}.$$

The **Divergence Theorem** states that when $E$ is a simple solid region, $S$ is the boundary of $E$ with positive (outward) orientation, and $\mathbf{F}$ is a vector field whose component functions have continuous partial derivatives on an open region that contains $E$, then we have  $$\iint_S\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}=\iiint_V\mathrm{div }\ \mathbf{F}dV .$$

Since $$\mathrm{div}\ \mathrm{curl}\ \mathbf{F}=0,$$ then why doesn't $\int_C\mathbf{F }\cdot d\mathbf{r}=\iint_S \mathrm{curl }\ \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}$ always vanish?  For by the divergence theorem we have
$$\int_C\mathbf{F }\cdot d\mathbf{r}=\iint_S \mathrm{curl }\ \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}=\iiint_V\mathrm{div }\ \mathrm{curl}\ \mathbf{F}dV =0.$$  But clearly this is not always true.

Where am I going wrong here?

- Is this true only when $S$ encloses another region $V$?
- Does $V$ need to be bounded to apply the divergence theorem?  For some reason I feel like this is not the case, but I am not sure.
- Is there an obvious physical interpretation to the above result?

Many thanks for your consideration.  This has stumped me for quite some time and I would be very grateful to anyone who could shed some insight.

Comment: I just noticed this link, and apologize for the dup.  I am not sure what Essam means when he writes 'remember that the divergence theorem is only applicable on "closed surfaces" '.  What does he mean by a 'closed surface'?  I assume that he doesn't mean a surface that contains all of its limit points.  Does he mean a surface $S$ that encloses another region $V$?  Does this mean that the divergence theorem is inapplicable on infinite or semi-infinite regions $V$?

Comment: As you say, $S$ must be the boundary of $V$, and $C$ must be the boundary of $S$. But "the boundary of a boundary is empty".

Comment: Ok, I think I got it.  But what do you mean by saying ' "the boundary of a boundary is empty". '?  Why is this relevant?  Sorry for being so dense!

Comment: Think of a region in $\Bbb R^3$, say the unit ball. Think of its boundary surface. Does that surface have a boundary curve?

Comment: One could draw a curve enclosing the boundary of the unit ball, but that curve would be a set of measure zero in two or three dimensional space.  So I would say, no, it does not.